# Update 2D numpy array values

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

Is there a more efficient way to update the values of a multidimensional numpy array?
For example, I have a loop

```
        for i in np.arange(5):
            for j in np.arange(5):  
                if (i + j) % 2 == 0:   
                    v[i,j] = v[i,j] + v[i, j + 1]
```

I was thinking on parallelizing this process later (with `multiprocessing` and `Pool`) but I can't imagine how. Maybe defining a function and using `map` but this is a 2D array and the operations depend on the element indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you are doing this:

[image]

You can do this in two lines using slice indexing:

```
v[0:5:2,0:5:2] += v[0:5:2,1:6:2]    # even rows
v[1:5:2,1:5:2] += v[1:5:2,2:6:2]    # odd rows
```

Comment: Your answer left even rows unchanged. Should have another statement dealing with that.

Comment: Seen. +1 for graphical illustration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the only way for doing this kind of computations? I have more complex operations on my code (that's why I said in my question this was an example), but basically, the even squares updates are independent of the odd squares updates. What I wanted was to parallelize all those computations.  If I use your answer, the code is lengthier than doing the for loops, but maybe is  faster. If I don't get more ideas I'll mark your idea as accepted, thanks again.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by "more complex" - could you maybe give another example? Also I'm not sure what you mean by "lengthier" - is two lines too long for you?

Comment: Yes, sorry. For example, I need to sum `v[i - 1, j] + v[i + 1, j] + v[i, j - 1] + v[i, j + 1]` and I have to make a matrix for each of them (my matrices are much larger, so I use a parameter instead of the `5` in my question) according to your answer, and two times for the different rows. By the way, I could implement my code with your proposition and it was way more faster than the `for` loops (thanks a lot for that), so I think it's better. I thought that parallelizing would be more effective but this optimization seems very effective.

Comment: Parallelization is usually the last tool you want to reach for in these situations. It's way more of a pain to implement well, it adds a lot more complexity and overhead, and for simple operations like this you will probably see little (if any) performance benefit. You're much better off learning to make the best of vectorization in numpy.